# how to solve magento errors as below,

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, error

> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/archtraders/stationerypoint/app/Mage.php on line 36
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/archtraders/stationerypoint/app/Mage.php on line 36
>
> Warning:
>   include(/home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on
>   line 94
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/archtraders/stationerypoint/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php
>   on line 94
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in
>   /home/archtraders/stationerypoint/app/Mage.php on line 670

web : www.stationerypoint.com.au

Comment: Have you check project set as "Developer" or "Producttion" mode ?

Comment: seems your compilation is on. disable it from file includes/config.php just comments out last 2 line by #

Comment: I am not used to with this, can i provide my login id of godaddy, can you pls check , pls help me guys... i will appreciate a lot ... thanks email me : naisuv@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

edit includes/config.php and change

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

to:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

Comment: prashant thai, i have tried this but its not working :( , can you pls help me , can i get your contact details, i will give you my godaddy id and password. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi check permissions to all files. It solve me all problems